# Keep getting [object Object] when sending axios post request

Tags: javascript, axios

I've been trying to work this out but couldn't resolve it yet.

This is my code-

```
    const sendData = () => {

        let config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }

        let data = {
            printer: '${PRINTER}',
            branch: '${BRANCHNAME}',
            date: '${DATE_SHIBUTZ}',
            track: '${TRACKCODE}',
            sern: '${SERNUM}'
        }

        let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data)

        axios.post("server url", jsonData, config)

    }
```

However, no matter what I try I keep getting an [object Object]. What am I doing wrong here?
I feel like this shouldn't be that complicated.

Much thanks!

Comment: The code provided doesn't produce the error given

Comment: You don't need to use `JSON.stringify` to transform `data`, just run `axios.post("server url", data, config)`

Comment: @Livio Tried that, same result

Comment: I've just stumbled upon this same problem and cant figure it out. Did you ever get to the bottom of it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending this request from a form? What content type is actually being sent?

I ask because I hit this issue while a request was being sent on submit of a form. I noticed that regardless of the content type I specified in the axios request headers, the content type was always being sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If you're in the same scenario, this may work. I dont know if this is the only solution, it's *a* solution; convert the JSON to a `FromData` object.

```js
const sendData = () => {

  // Might not need this any more
  // let config = {
  //     headers: {
  //         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  //     }
  // }

  let data = new FormData();
  data.append('printer', PRINTER),
  data.append('branch', BRANCHNAME),
  data.append('date', DATE_SHIBUTZ)',
  data.append('track',TRACKCODE),
  data.append('sern', SERNUM')

  axios.post("server url", data)

}
```

I'll admin that I'm very new to working with forms so I dont know much on them. Is it possible to send JSON content from a form? I dont know.